# Should I use a direct function call in an if condition or first store to a variable?

Tags: c++

In the following code, what is the preferred way of checking the if condition:
Using the variable `agex`, or a direct function call (as done below)?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{ public:
  int age;
  bool checkAgeMinor();
};

bool A::checkAgeMinor()
{
  if(age >= 18)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
  A a;

  bool agex = a.checkAgeMinor();
  cout<<"Age is"<<agex<<std::endl;

  if(!a.checkAgeMinor()) // should I use agex here instead
  {
    std::cout<<"age less than 18"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  if(a.checkAgeMinor())
  {
    std::cout<<"Do something"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. What do you mean with "optimum"? Fastest? Easiest to read? Most resilient against future code changes?

Comment: Don't try to outsmart the compiler. My bet would be regardless of whether you use the variable or the function call it will be compiled to the same assembly code

Comment: Something that should be a best practice @MaxLanghof

Comment: @VinayShukla if you don't use the result again I would suggest against creating a temporary variable. If you need to access the value multiple times I would create a temporary. 
Not (only) in terms of performance but readability.

Comment: i've seen it so many times, but why  if (condition) return true; else return false; why not just return condition ?

Comment: @AndrewKashpur There's no reason in doing so, I also prefer `return condition;`

Comment: BTW obligatory warning here not to get too hung up on "best practice" in general; there's often no such thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i'm talking about A::checkAgeMinor()

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Oh, right, my mistake! Then I would say that it's entirely subjective. Sometimes I prefer to read the conditions distinctly, as if going down a checklist; sometimes, a trivial condition is best just got out of the way in-line. I'm not sure I have a particularly strong opinion on which I prefer in this case, though I'd _probably_ have written `return (age >= 18);` yes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a very simplistic viewpoint and assume we dont know what `checkAgeMinor()` is actually doing. You use the value it returns 3 times. Now lets assume the value it returns could change in between the places where you are using the value. Would your code be correct if that would be the case? No.

What you actually want is 3 times the same value, otherwise you would get inconsistent output. Dont waste time to ponder about implementation details but consider what the code in the current scope is supposed to do. It is not supposed to react on sudden changes of the `checkAgeMinor` but it is supposed to call the method to get the value and do something based on that value. So what you actually want is:

```
bool agex = a.checkAgeMinor();
std::cout << "Age is" << agex << '\n';
if(!agex) 
{
   std::cout << "age less than 18" << '\n';
   return 1;
} else {
   std::cout << "Do something" << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

PS: whitespaces don't hurt and `std::endl` does more than ending a line, you should use `'\n'` instead (unless you really want to flush the stream).

Answer (score 0):

You already checked the age; you don't need to check it again.

You have this information in a `bool` already, so *use it*. Make it `const` for good measure.

Only if you had reason to believe the value might have *changed* in the meantime (or if there are serious readability issues) would you go and invoke that function a second time.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use the function call result multiple times (as here: Printing
  it, then checking it), I would advise to store it to a variable and
  then just use the variable. This is a safe method and will not break
  if someone decides that the function should have side effects, which
  may yield unexpected results if you call the function multiple times.
- However, if the function has a good name and can be expected to have
  no side effects/significant running time, then it is completely OK to
  call it directly multiple times. An example for that would be a
  getter like `getAge()`, which will presumably not do any computation
  and will have no side effects.
- Another point to note is that **if the function result may change**
  (for whatever reason), you would obviously have to call it again to
  get an updated result. In your case, it seems unreasonable that the
  age would change in the middle of the code, so calling the function
  multiple times won't do much.

Note how I have not made any comments about performance. That's because unless your function is expensive, the difference between calling it multiple times and calling it once will be basically irrelevant. Storing a `bool` to a variable is also more or less free to the compiler (because your CPU works with registers anyway), so **there will be no measurable difference between storing the function result or using it directly**. You should not worry about this until you can *prove* that there is a performance issue.

---

As for your concrete example:

You already stored the bool once. At that point, just keep using it. Calling the function again is of no use (unless its result could be different, but the age changing is not expected here, and the code would break if it did). Also, the second `if` should just be the `else` branch of the first one. While you are at it, you could give the variable a better name:

```
  // Returns whether age >= 18, I find the function name confusing...
  bool isAdult = a.checkAgeMinor();
  // What does "Age is true" mean?
  cout << "Age is " << isAdult << std::endl;

  if (!isAdult)
  {
    std::cout << "age less than 18" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Do something" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `agex`. As per my understanding, what you are doing will invoke the function again and there will be some computation time involved in changing program counter, assigning memory to the calling function etc. While in the other case, we just see what's the value at that particular memory location. So it just involves a look up.

Comment: I also have similar opinion but is the overhead of creating variable more optimal than a function call ??

Comment: @VinayShukla Why do you care which one is faster? In the program you show, there will be no measurable difference. Making your program two nanoseconds faster is pointless.

Comment: @VinayShukla Computing several times in your case is more overhead then storing the result, to compare it the result needs to hold anywhere anyhow

Comment: I think it actually depends upon the function. If the function is a smaller one then may be incoming function will be better. But if there are let's say,1000 lines in that function then calling function again and again won't be a good idea.

Comment: i didnt downvote, but i disagree with your reasoning. For the given code, performance should be the last concern (actually I cant really follow your "changing program counter, assigning memory to calling function etc" argument), but rather readability and clarity of the code

Comment: Ohh, no problem. I meant the overhead due to the function call.

Comment: compare the overhead due to a function call to the time it takes to call `std::cout` and you will realize that it really does not matter

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks.